# Running shell_exec() to execute python script on Google Cloud Compute VM Instance

Tags: php, python, google-cloud-platform

I am developing an app that does something in three steps, on a virtual machine in the computer engine of Google Cloud:

- 1 - takes input from the user in the form of a form
- 2 - passes the input to a .php file using `$_POST[]`, which then runs a shell_exec command (after checking through `escapecmd()`) to run a python script (The command is `sudo python3 A1.py I1 I2 ... IN`) where `I1, I2, ... IN` are inputs from the form.
- 3 - The python script writes the output to a .txt file, which is then parsed by the PHP script, and the output is displayed.

So now my problem is that running `sudo python3 A1.py I1 I2 ... IN` from the terminal works fine, as it updates the tmp.txt file which is updated on the PHP file, and shows correct output. However, going to the app itself, if I change the values in the form to `I1 I2 ... IN`, then the same output is displayed as earlier, i.e. in step 2, the `shell_exec()` command is not working. 
Thus the command works from the terminal, but not from inside the `shell_exec()`command in PHP. Doing `$output = shell_exec($cmd); var_dump($output);` only returns a NULL value. I have checked the rest of my code, all commands seem to be working normally, and the value of $cmd is the same as what I type into the terminal. I think this has something to do with permissions, as I am running Apache2 with PHP7.0 on the Compute Engine Instance.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
...
$path ="sudo python3 A1.py  ".$I1." ".$I2." ".$I3." ".$I4;
$command = escapeshellcmd($path);
$output = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($output);//Shows NULL
echo $output;//shows nothing
echo $command."\n";//Shows sudo python3 A1.py I1 I2 I3 I4
$file = file_get_contents('tmp.txt');
echo $file;
...
?>
```

Expected results - The value of output should change with change in the input form
Actual results - The command changes with change in input form values, but the result remains the same as that of the last terminal computation, and does not change with change in values of inputs. Hence `shell_exec()` does not seem to be executing properly.

Can someone tell me how to fix this in the Linux VM Instance?

Comment: Where is your code writing to `tmp.txt`?

Comment: In Python. The output is stored in tmp.txt

Comment: Your code does not show the creation or writing to tmp.txt. I think that is where your problem is.

Comment: Hey, I think there is a bit of a miscommunication. I use shell_exec() to execute a python script, which writes the output to a tmp.txt file. Here, in the PHP program, I am accessing that tmp.txt file, and reading the output and printing it through `echo.` There are multiple reasons why I don't think this is the issue - firstly, running this command from the command line, gives perfect results, reading/writing/computation from tmp.txt works. Secondly, when I run the PHP file, it reads the output from tmp.txt perfectly - the only issue is that the output is from the previous run of the program.

Comment: I am using dates as an input to the Python file, so let me give an example here: suppose I enter 2 October 2015 in the terminal of the VM, I get output corresponding to that input. But, on the other hand, if I enter 3 November 2016 from the HTML form, pass that data to PHP, echoing `$command` shows the command sending that input, but shell_exec doesn't seem to executing that command, and the output I see is from 2 October 2015 only. Like I said, the code works perfectly in the terminal, but not using shell_exec, which is why I think there is a Linux permissions error stopping its use.